# Why can't compilers automatically optimize regular recursion?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, theory, compiler-theory

In nearly every functional programming tutorial, a large section is dedicated to teaching you how to convert algorithms to a tail-recursive format, since this can be optimized to a loop.

This is fine, but it made me wonder why compilers cannot automatically convert an algorithm using "regular" recursion to use a separate stack object (allocated on the heap), and then convert the algorithm to something iterative.

I don't fully understand how the CHICKEN Scheme or Haskell compilers work (which I hear might be immune to stack overflows), but perhaps they are doing something like this?  If so, why can't this be done in most languages?

I'm not saying this to badmouth compiler engineers, I just genuinely have no idea how this stuff works but would love to learn.

Comment: This us a very broad question but there certainly are lots of learning resources still available (although there is a distressing tendency to build paywalls around seminal papers from two or three decades ago). Here's Henry Baker's paper on archive.org, for example: https://web.archive.org/web/20190202232914/http://home.pipeline.com/~hbaker1/CheneyMTA.html

Comment: The bottom line: yes, they can but there is a cost. And you only pay a cost if you're convinced of the value of the result. Some language designers (and users) have this conviction; others don't.

Comment: @rici I am assuming that the cost you are speaking of is in terms of performance?  Or do you mean in terms of developer time?

Comment: yes, performance. Although it also makes the runtime support more complicated (garbage collection, for example), which is also a cost.

Comment: @rici What's stopping C++<new-version-in-the-distant-future> from introducing something like a `rec` keyword (such as what you'd see in OCaml) that forgoes the traditional stack *for that function only*, and using the regular stack for anything else?  Does what I suggested necessitate a runtime?

Comment: Nothing except the lack of a detailed proposal which could convince the committee of its utility. (In other words, don't hold your breath.) Note that there are open forums for discussing the C++ standard, but that does not include comments threads on StackOverflow. See https://isocpp.org/

Comment: I'm not asking about C++ specifically (I don't program in it), more of an example of "this is a low-level language that traditionally does not have a runtime".

Comment: @rici You have been very helpful.  If you formulate your comments into a response I will select it.

Comment: c++ definitely has a runtime. Among other things, it needs it to unwind the stack (and call destructors) when an exception is raised. There are other C++ features (and even C features) which require runtime support, including the parts of the standard library required even for freestanding implementations, many of which cannot be written in portable C++. I'll think about converting the comments.

Comment: A CPS-transform is exactly this. All your calls become tail calls.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a difference between cannot and currently do not

As your suggestion is not what would be technically called hard, that is would not complete, or would not complete in your lifetime, it seems they in fact could

the implied question of why they do not is speculation, but likely based on how much resources it would take to guarantee the same results with or without the optimization

i do not miss the days of large uncertainty of the optimization level causing a bug, so I am happy to wait for this until its perfect

as far as i know, there is nothing in the standard precluding this optimization